# php inheritance: children classes to inherit the data in the parent class?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, php-5.4

Sometimes I get lost and started to doubt whether I am doing right in writing classes in php.

For instance, these are quite basic and simple classes,

```
class base {

    protected $connection = null;

    /**
     * Set the contructor for receiving data.
     */
    public function __construct($connection)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;

    }

    public function method()
    {
        print_r(get_object_vars($this));
    }

}

class child extends base{

    public function __construct(){
    }

    public function method()
    {
        print_r(get_object_vars($this));
    }
}
```

I have the `child` class extended from the `base`. And I pass some data/ info into `base` class. And I want the `child` class inherited the data/ info that I just passed. For instance,

```
$base = new base("hello");

$child = new child(); 
$child->method();
```

So I would assume I get `Array ( [connection] => hello )` as my answer.

But I get this actually `Array ( [connection] => )`

So that means I have to pass that piece of data every time into the **children classes** which extended from the base. otherwise I won't get `Array ( [connection] => hello )` as my answer.

Is there a correct way to write the children classes to inherit the passed data from the parent class?

Comment: Why not just assign the 'hello' in the constructor for instance then all is set...there is no connection between those two instantiated classes so that the child can inherit the 'hellp'

Comment: sorry, I don't get it. could you please give me an example? thanks.

Comment: awww. ignore it. I got it now.

Comment: my problem is the data must be passed from outside. cannot be set in the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're mixing up the template (the class) and the objects (instances of a class) somehow.

- How would instanciating one object of class `base` with some given initial values have any impact on other objects of class `child`?
  **Instances** of class `child` WILL NOT dynamically "inherit" some property of an **instance** of class `base`.
- If you want to initialize some protected properties from your `base` class `__construct` method, and if you want that to be possible also from your `child` class without having to re-write the `__construct` method, then you must NOT overwrite the `__construct` method of your `child` class.

Comment: thanks for the reply. how do I `NOT overwrite the __construct method of your child class.`?